# App on Android Studio Emulator Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

[image: Android error screenshot]
My App does not have any errors in it and the emulator seems to be working and turned on. However for some reason, my app cannot start on the emulator. Any suggestions?

After going and trying Genymotion, this came up in the console

```
  Target device: genymotion-       preview___google_nexus_5x___6_0_0___api_23___1080x1920-192.168.57.101:5555
Installing APK: /Users/shred13/AndroidStudioProjects/Snow/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/shrey.edu.self.snow
Installing shrey.edu.self.snow
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/shrey.edu.self.snow"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/shrey.edu.self.snow
Success


    Launching application: shrey.edu.self.snow/shrey.edu.self.snow.MainActivity.
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n        "shrey.edu.self.snow/shrey.edu.self.snow.MainActivity" -a      android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=shrey.edu.self.snow/.MainActivity }
```

This is the code around line 19

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
              //Line 19 under 
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }
```

Comment: Are your simulator installed google play store ?

Comment: Hi there! It seems that your app crashed while executing. Perhaps you can try to print out console messages to figure out where the app went wrong. Some sample code can help too!

Comment: @TheMuffinCoder according to the console messages everything went well, do you think it might be something that looks right but is wrong?

Comment: @DanhDC sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Some simulator missing google Play store. So, if your project have target **Google APIs** , it wil crash.

Comment: @DanhDC I don't think I put any Google APIs, thanks though

Comment: Maybe, problem occur in **Toolbar** , show your code in **MainActivity.java line 19**

Comment: @DanhDC uploaded the code at line 19 and around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had an extra line of code in which there was a toolbar on line 19 that the computer did know what to do with. After deleting it, the app worked

Answer (score 0):

You can using Droid4x. It is emulator for android. This is emulator better Google's emulator
Home page: http://www.droid4x.com/
Link Download: http://dl.haima.me/download/DXDown/win/Z001/Droid4XInstaller.exe

Comment: Try to use **Genymotion** https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download , it very useful for dev